# Workaround for joining two streams in structured streaming in Spark 2.x

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a stream of configurations (not changed often, but if there's an update, it will be a message), and another stream of raw data points.

As I understand that for now spark doesn't support joining to streaming datasets or dataframes. Is there a good way to workaround this?

Is it possible to "snapshot" one of the streaming dataset to a static dataset (probably the configuration one, since it has less updates), then join with the other streaming dataset?

Open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I'm doing at the end.

Put the stream with less updates into a memory sink. Then do a select from the that table. By this time, it is a static instance and can be joined with the other stream. No trigger needed. Of course, you need to update the table correctly by yourself.

This is not very robust, but that's the best one I can come up with before the official support.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet that you can share to understand this even better? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Workaround" is to use current master branch ;)

It's not released yet, but current master branch already has stream-stream inner join and there is outer join in progress. See [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18791) Jira ticket for reference, in sub-task you see possible joins to use.

There's no other easy workaround. Streaming joins requires saving state of streams and then correct updates of state. You can see code in pull requests, it's quite complex to implement stream-stream join.

Comment: It is 3.0 not 2.3 :)

Comment: Hmm, Target Version is 2.3, but Fix Version is 3.0 - it's already in master, do you think it won't be included in 2.3?

Comment: It sounds like a serious change. It might be deliberate choice. But I am not an insider so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: @zero323 Ok, I wrote to Tathagata Das :) Maybe he knows - https://twitter.com/GawedaTomasz/status/912423624044421122

Comment: How about creating a temp view from one of the dataframe or dataset? Then do the join. According to "definitive guide", "Effectively, views are equivalent to creating a new DataFrame from an existing DataFrame."