# Does Spark 2.2.0 support Streaming Self-Joins?

Tags: apache-spark

I understand JOINS of two different dataframes are not supported in Spark 2.2.0 but I am trying to do self-join so only one stream. Below is my code

```
val jdf = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "join_test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load();

jdf.printSchema
```

which print the following

```
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

Now I run the join query below after reading through this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248652/cleanest-most-efficient-syntax-to-perform-dataframe-self-join-in-spark)

```
jdf.as("jdf1").join(jdf.as("jdf2"), $"jdf1.key" === $"jdf2.key")
```

And I get the following Exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`jdf1.key`' given input columns: [timestamp, value, partition, timestampType, topic, offset, key];;
'Join Inner, ('jdf1.key = 'jdf2.key)
:- SubqueryAlias jdf1
:  +- StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@f662b5,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(startingOffsets -> earliest, subscribe -> join_test, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092),None), kafka, [key#243, value#244, topic#245, partition#246, offset#247L, timestamp#248, timestampType#249]
+- SubqueryAlias jdf2
   +- StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@f662b5,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(startingOffsets -> earliest, subscribe -> join_test, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092),None), kafka, [key#243, value#244, topic#245, partition#246, offset#247L, timestamp#248, timestampType#249]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not create any difference if we try to join same streaming data frame or different dataframe.So, It will not be supported.

There are two ways to achieve it.

First, you can join static and streaming dataframe. So, read once as batch data and next as streaming df.
The second solution, you can use Kafka streams. It provides joining of streaming data.

Comment: you maybe right but the error says something else. It says cannot resolve '`jdf1.key`'. It doesn't say JOINS not supported!

Comment: It might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412884/workaround-for-joining-two-streams-in-structured-streaming-in-spark-2-x

Comment: got it! but I would love to see UnsupportedOperationException...instead I am seeing something else in the above code.